# Auth. Provider vs Single Sign-On Settings

Tags: saml, identity, oidc

Within Salesforce Setup there are two options:

1. Auth. Provider
2. Single Sign-On Settings

When setting up both, both can be added to the Org 'My Domain' login page and Experience cloud pages.

What is the difference between both settings?

When would/should I use Auth. Provider vs Single Sign-On Settings?

Any scenarios to help explain would be incredibly helpful. It's a topic I'm really struggling to get my head around and the Salesforce Help docs don't seem to differentiate.

** Edit - I thought it may have to do with JIT, but SSO Settings have JIT, however you can implement JIT within the Registration Handler for Auth. Provider settings?

The only difference I see is one uses OIDC and the other SAML?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Auth. Provider settings would be set up for customer identity where as Single Sign-on would be set up for internal Identity. Though it does feel like the lines are blurred so I can see the confusion.

Auth. Providers could be Facebook - allow people to self reg to your community (NOT YOUR ORG, that would be terrible).

SSO Settings - to allow internal users to log into Salesforce using your identity provider such as Azure or Okta with JIT implemented so you don't have to create them in Salesforce once you create them in Azure.